# htaccess https www (only) to https non-www (only)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I rewrite all traffic using "https" and "www" to "https" without the "www". I do not want any rewrites done on non-ssl traffic (besides the existing code below). I also already have a rewrite for clean urls going on at the same time. The SSL cert is purchased on the non-www URL which is why I am asking how to do this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks for your time.

[EDIT]

Ended up getting this to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: this is for http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't understand your comment?

Comment: your question is OT here, also it's already been answered on ServerFault multiple times http://serverfault.com/search?q=htaccess+www